# How do you draw a border around a shape that is a series of paths in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a custom Shape in SwiftUI that is a series of CGPoints that form different lines.

I want to be able to draw a border around each individual path and right now the only thing I can think of is creating another Shape that takes the original CGPoints and adds x,y padding to each point but I wanted to see if there was another way that perhaps is built-in that I couldn't find.

For example, my shape is

```
      -----
           |
           |
```

and I want to add a border Shape so I can detect when someone is in a bound where the # represents a new possible Shape around the original paths.

```
     ######## 
     #----- #
      ######
          #|#
          #|#
           #
```

Is there a way to implement this that is built in?

edit: code I'm currently thinking about to draw the border, very early but gives a gist of what I'm thinking

```
struct DrawShapeBorder: Shape {
    var points: [CGPoint]

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path: Path = Path()

        guard let startingPoint = points.first else {
            return path
        }

        // go up
        let upStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: startingPoint.x, y: startingPoint.y + 5)
        path.move(to: upStartingPoint)

        for pointLocation in points {
            
            path.addLine(to: pointLocation)
        }

        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code so far?

Comment: added the code, forgot about that sorry!

Comment: Why not just set a background/overlay with the same shape, but a frame one pixel larger?

Comment: @Ryan oh awesome, would that be this function? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(_:alignment:) not sure how to make it a pixel larger though

Comment: yeah. use .frame() to set a frame and the shape will resize to that. otherwise use stroke or strokeBorder. Depends on your exact shape etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Evergreen suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341139/how-do-you-draw-a-border-around-a-shape-that-is-a-series-of-paths-in-swiftui?noredirect=1#comment119029842_67341221) in the comments, you can use the `stroke` modifier... but the tricky thing is that you can only apply one of these, so you can't do `.stroke().stroke().stroke()`, unlike `.shadow().shadow().shadow()`.

However, you can work around this by using a `ZStack` containing 2 copies of the shape, then adding a different stroke to each of them.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DrawShapeBorder(points: [
            CGPoint(x: 100, y: 150),
            CGPoint(x: 300, y: 100),
            CGPoint(x: 300, y: 200),
            CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200)
        ])
        .stroked()
    }
}
struct DrawShapeBorder: Shape {
    
    /// add the double border
    func stroked() -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self.stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            self.stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
        }
    }
    
    var points: [CGPoint]
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path: Path = Path()
        
        guard let startingPoint = points.first else {
            return path
        }
        
        // go up
        let upStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: startingPoint.x, y: startingPoint.y + 5)
        path.move(to: upStartingPoint)
        
        for pointLocation in points {
            path.addLine(to: pointLocation)
        }
        
        return path
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Path with white border, but extra red border around it]

Comment: Oooh! I just tried this and it works as does overlay, now I just need to figure out how to detect someone is within the border of the larger lineWidth stroke. Any tips on that?

Comment: @elyakshaver not sure. You would need to convert the border path into a shape path somehow... I have no idea how to do that though...

Comment: that's fair. I'll explore it and probably ask another question at some point soon. :]

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in function for this.

A very 'bug bug' fix for this is a very strong shadow repeated several times.

```
Text()
.shadow().shadow().shadow().shadow().shadow().shadow().shadow().shadow().shadow().shadow().shadow()
```

Yes, not ideal but it should work.

Comment: this is pretty cool, I didn't know about shadow

Comment: you can also look into border and stroke modifiers. these both feel promising.